# How Can I specify hawq ssh port?

Tags: ssh, key, port, hawq

How can I specify the ssh port ,my ssh port is 333.When I ssh remote host,the hawq ssh port is 22.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Delete `#` from line `#port 22` and replace `22` by `333`.
- Update your firewall
- Restart the `sshd service`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change ssh port in hawq.
Instead, ssh is an operating system utility. So, you can change it from operating system perspective.